# How to print 8 times the same label in order

Tags: ms-word, label, ms-office, mailmerge

I can't figure it out how can I print more same labels in order. Every time I got next record only. I need to have every record 8 times consecutively. I get this values from excel sheet. In the second picture there is how it should look like.

What I get

[image]

How it should look

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the "Next record" field code. Then the same record will be written until a "Next record" field is encountered.

1. Press Alt+F9 to display the field codes
2. Select each next field you don't want. It will look like: { NEXT }
3. Delete the selection (the field)
4. When you're done, Alt+F9 again to toggle back to the result display

Comment: @Cindy_Meister The problem is that this works only for label where I deleted NEXT. I have about 300 records and I need that every one must be written 8 times in order. This doesn't work for me or I may do something wrong.

Comment: @Cindy_Meister Yeah, I did something wrong. You must delete {NEXT} from whole page and then it will be replicated to other pages. It was my bad. Thanks for help.